# Selective TLS connection fail

Tags: windows, powershell, security, ssl, tls

I have a VB.NET application that connects to a remote server, which I have no authority whatsoever, via a username/password, retrieves some data and populates a local database.

Lately the application stopped working and began sending the error

> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

or

> Inner Exception: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Going through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2859790/13826315) and performing what is recommended there, I am still facing the same issue from a particular computer running *Windows Server 2019* that was upgraded from *2012*, porting the executables to another computer it runs fine.
I ran **IIS Crypto** on both server and other PCs and applying their recommended best practices on both, it persisted.

I concluded that this particular PC has some outdated cipher or certificate that is preventing the connection.

How can I get a list (cmd, PowerShell, …) of whatever is causing the security issue from the 2 computers in order
to compare and find the culprit?

Comment: If you can reproduce the error then I would try to make a Wireshark traffic dump to get the details of the TLS handshake and to identify if the client or the server has ended the handshake/connection.

Comment: I doubt they will install Wireshark on the server that connects to it. They usually run small utilities like IIS Crypto.

Comment: So the VB.NET application is running also on a server? That detail wasn't included in your question. because you can run Wireshark on the server or the client - the observed network data you want is the same on both sides.

Comment: Sorry if I created a misunderstanding. The application itself is deployed on a server in the same work location. But administrator access is denied for developers. The access is reserved for deployment administrators. But what I try connecting to is not on premise, probably on a different continent.